# Magento - Multiselect color attribute

Tags: magento

is it possible to create products in Magento with one or more colors ? For example a T-shirt can be "red", "white" or/and "red and white" (composed with 2 or more colours) ??

I want to have a multiselect in the color attribute and not only one colour in a list box.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you make one of the simple products of your configurable product have "red/white" as color? In your example, you'd create 3 simple product, 1 red, 1 white, 1 red and white.
Then you join them in 1 configurable product, and so in the frontend you'd have 1 simple select with the 3 options, red, white and "red and white".
I know this is not exactly what you're asking, but maybe it would suit your need, and this way you don't have to write a module.
Hope that helps